# AutoFillHints with two parameters in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

In my `TextFormField` I want autofill both `email` and `telephoneNumber`, but when I write like this, it's not working. Is this true way for using two `autofillHints` with two parameters?

```
TextFormField(
    autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email, AutofillHints.telephoneNumber],
     decoration: const InputDecoration(
     labelText: 'Label text',
     hintText: 'hint text',
  )
)
```

Comment: you have two text fields?

Comment: no, I have one textField,

Comment: one text form field for two separate data?

Comment: yes, in 'log in' screen for username can be email or telephone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html

On iOS, only the first hint in the list is accounted for. The hint will be translated to a UITextContentType.